# What is the sum of $1+(1-i)^2-(1-i)^4+(1-i)^6-(1-i)^8+...-(1-i)^{100}$?

Tags: complex-numbers, summation

I'm trying to find the sum of:
$$
1+(1-i)^2-(1-i)^4+(1-i)^6-(1-i)^8+...-(1-i)^{100}
$$

I'm aware that converting to $(-2i)^2$ might make more sense but I still can't get a final formulated sum. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you separate this out into two separate geometric series and add the results? Also, for consistency, the first term should be negative one, no?

Comment: @RossMillikan Technically the negative of that since the sign flips, but essentially correct

Comment: @barrycarter:  I missed the sign flips

Comment: Let $S=1+(1-i)^2-...-(1-i)^{100}$, then $S(1-i)^2=$ $(1-i)^2+(1-i)^4-(1-i)^6+...+(1-i)^{100}-(1-i)^{102}=$ $1+2(1-i)^2-S-(1-i)^{102}$. One can express $S$ from here. To calculate $(1-i)^{102}$ one can use exponential form of $1-i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&1+(1-i)^2-(1-i)^4+(1-i)^6-(1-i)^8+...-(1-i)^{100}
\\
=&1+\frac{(2i)(1-(2i)^{50})}{1-2i}
\\
=&\frac{1-2^{52}}5+\frac{2^{51}+2}5i
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? I think the $r$ you're choosing might need to be on the opposite sign

Comment: You are indeed right!

Comment: While you have re-written the series in terms of powers of $ \ 2i \ $ correctly, the sum expression should then be $$ 1 \ \color{red}{-} \ \frac{(2i)·( \ 1 \ - \ [2i]^{50} \ )}{1 \ - \ 2i} \ \ . $$  [see my post]

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$\displaystyle \frac{1 + z^{2k+1}}{1 + z} = 1 - z + z^2 - z^3 \;+\;...\;+\; z^{2k}$

Answer (score 0):

About your concern about working with $ \ (-2i)^{k} \ $ as the terms of this geometric series, it is helpful to be systematic about the sequence of terms:

$$ (1 \ - \ i)^{ \ 2k} \ \ = \ \ (-2i)^{ \ k} \ \ = \ \  \begin{array}{cc}
-2^k·i \ \ , &  k \ \equiv \  1 \ \ [\text{mod} \ 4]  \\ -2^{2k}  \ \ , &  k \ \equiv \  2 \ \ [\text{mod} \ 4]  \\ 2^k·i \ \ , &  k \ \equiv \  3 \ \ [\text{mod} \ 4]  \\ 2^{2k}  \ \ , &  k \ \equiv \  0 \ \ [\text{mod} \ 4]  \end{array} \ \ \ , \ \ \ k \ \in \ \mathbb{N} \ \ . $$

We note that the first several terms of the sum $ \ 
1 + (-2i) - (-4) + (8i) - (16) + (-32i) - (-64) + (128i) - (256) + \ \ldots \ $ indicate that the series after the first term may be described by groups of four terms (-imaginary) - (-real) + (+imaginary) - (+real) , which can be separated into two separate series with the sum of real terms subtracted from the sum of imaginary terms.  In each of these series, the ratio of successive terms is $ \ (-2i)^2 \ = \ -4 \ \ . \ $  The last imaginary term is $ \ (1 - i)^{98} \ = \ (-2i)^{49} \ $ and the last real term is $ \ (1 - i)^{100} \ = \ (-2i)^{50} \ \ , \ $ so we may express our series as

$$ 1 \ + \ \sum_{n \ = \ 0}^{24} \ (-2i)·(-4)^n \ - \ \sum_{n \ = \ 0}^{24} \ (-4)·(-4)^n \ \ \ ,  $$

for which the formula for the sum of finite geometric series gives
$$ = \ \ 1 \ \  + \ \  (-2i)  ·  \frac{1 \ - \ (-4)^{24 \ + \ 1}}{1 \ - \ (-4)} \ \ - \ \ (-4)  ·  \frac{1 \ - \ (-4)^{24 \ + \ 1}}{1 \ - \ (-4)}   $$
$$ = \ \ 1 \ + \ \frac{4 \ + \ 4^{26}}{5} \ \ + \ \ (-2i)  ·  \frac{1 \ + \ 4^{25}}{5} \ \ = \ \ \frac{9 \ + \ 4^{26}}{5} \ \ - \ \ i  ·  \frac{2·(1 \ + \ 4^{25})}{5} \ \ . $$

The sum found by **Federico Yu**  differs due to a sign error.  While the series is set up correctly as

$$ 1 \ + \ (1-i)^2 \ - \ (1-i)^4 \ + \ (1-i)^6 \ -(1-i)^8 \ + \ \ldots \ - \ (1-i)^{100} $$

$$ = \ \ 1 \ + \ (-2i) \ - \ (-2i)^2 \ + \ (-2i)^3 \ - \ (-2i)^4 \ + \ \ldots \ - \ (-2i)^{50} $$

$$ = \ \ 1 \ - \ (2i) \ - \ (2i)^2 \ - \ (2i)^3 \ - \ (2i)^4 \ - \ \ldots \ - \ (2i)^{50} \ \ , $$

this makes the sum
$$ 1 \  \color{red}{-} \  \sum_{n \ = \ 0}^{49} \ (2i)·(2i)^k \ \  = \ \ 1 \ - \ \frac{2i·(1 \ - \ (2i)^{50})}{1 \ - \ 2i} $$

$$ = \ \ 1 \ - \ \frac{( \ 2i \ - \ [2i]^{51} \ )·(1 \ + \ 2i)}{5} \ \  = \ \ 1 \ - \ \frac{ 2i \ + \ (2i)^2 \ - \ (2i)^{51} \ - \ (2i)^{52} }{5} $$ $$  = \ \ \left( \ \frac{5 \ - \ (-4) \ + \ 2^{52}}{5} \right) \ - \ i·\left( \ \frac{2 \ + \ 2^{51}}{5} \right) = \ \ \left( \ \frac{9 \ + \ 2^{52}}{5} \right) \ - \ i·\left( \ \frac{2 \ + \ 2^{51}}{5} \right) \ \ . $$

This can be checked by writing the sum equivalently as

$$ 2 \ - \  \sum_{n \ = \ 1}^{50} \ (2i)^k \ \  = \ \ 2 \ - \ \frac{( \ 1 \ - \ [2i]^{51} \ )}{1 \ - \ 2i} \ \  = \ \ 2 \ - \ \frac{( \ 1 \ - \ [2i]^{51} \ )·(1 \ + \ 2i)}{5} $$

$$ = \ \ 2 \ - \ \frac{ 1 \ + \ 2i \ - \ (2i)^{51} \ - \ (2i)^{52} }{5} \ \ = \ \ \frac{ 10 \ - \ 1 \ - \ 2i \ - \  2^{51}·i \ + \ 2^{52} }{5} \ \ , $$

as before.